# How to test post authentication web site (i.e secured resources) in whitebox?

Tags: penetration-test

I have a web app which is has a login portal and secured pages only accessible when login is accepted. 
I'm in a whitebox scenario and I want to pentest pages beyond the login portal.
My problem is I don't know tools or how to make use of the authorized logged in session data (cookies, etc...,) in my vulnerability scanner or in burp to pentest potected pages as those only accept authenticated requests...

I hope it's not to broad to ask for your suggestions

Comment: are you asking us how to conduct a pen test on web apps?

Comment: @VipulNair Hahahaha so that's what my OP implies ? ok nevermind then. I'm actually new in the field so bear with me this layman question

Comment: No.That's what i understood from your question.If it's something else you can clarify.

Comment: @VipulNair Yeah you are correct. Any heads up here ?. Also, more specifically, I saw in a vulnerability scanner I used an option asking to define if there is a login sequence.... I guess it would start scanning from the login sequence. And then using the results (on successful login) perform scanning on protected resources.... So in my OP, I meant how would I do this manually...